# Babel don't compile .graphql files inside the build folder on "babel server --out-dir build"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, ecmascript-6, graphql

**Some introduction:**

Our app uses Heroku as a server.
So, after pushing code it runs `npm start` as in my package.json

My current version of nodeJS in a laptop: v8.16.2, npm: 6.4.1.

In package.json:

`"engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },`

**The problem**:

Currently, it runs like this `"start": "node build/index.js"`
. Last changes were about adding graphql files.

npm start show `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/build/apollo/nCourse/nCourse.graphql'`

We don't run with `node server/index.js` because of using new ecma script features(not common js) like import and export

**The question**

I see two solutions in this problem

1. Make something which will create the file with graphql extension in build folder
2. Maybe update version of nodeJS if it can understand es import and export

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "wunder-education",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "server": "nodemon --exec babel-node server/index.js",
    "server:prodDB": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://saturdaykids:52turdayk1ds3@ds117866.mlab.com:17866/saturdaykids-prod nodemon --exec babel-node server/index.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules",
    "clean:admin": "npm run clean --prefix admin",
    "clean:all": "concurrently \"npm run clean\" \"npm run clean:admin\"",
    "install:admin": "npm install --prefix admin",
    "admin": "npm run start --prefix admin",
    "build:admin": "npm run build --prefix admin",
    "build:server": "babel server --out-dir build",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run build:server\" \"npm run build:admin\"",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run admin\"",
    "postinstall": "npm run install:admin",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "format:server": "prettier --write server/**/**/**/*.js",
    "format:admin": "prettier --write admin/src/**/**/*.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
    "@badgeup/badgeup-node-client": "^2.0.3",
    "airtable": "^0.5.10",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.9.13",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.456.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-force-https": "^1.0.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.2",
    "mongoose-fill": "^1.7.0",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "nan": "^2.14.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "supertest": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your package.json file ?

Comment: Actually, in build command it runs babel server --out-dir build

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya, Ok

Comment: have you checked the call stack in local ? is it crashing from index.js ?

Comment: Yes, it crashed too
I find some solution, gonna post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it solved by copy and pasting .graphql files inside the build/apollo by this command

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include 'server/apollo/*' --include '*.graphql' 'server/apollo' 'build'
```

In package.json:

```
"syncGraphql": "rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include 'server/apollo/*' --include '*.graphql' 'server/apollo' 'build'",

"build": "concurrently \"npm run build:server\" \"npm run build:admin\" \"npm run syncGraphql\"",
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) was my choice too.

I used it slightly differently like so:

```
"script": {
  ...
  "rsync:graphql": "rsync -r --include '*/' --include '*.graphql' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs 'src/' 'dist/'",
  "build": "BABEL_ENV=build babel src -d dist --source-maps --no-comments && npm run rsync:graphql",
  ...
}
```

In short, it saying: recursively copy all `.graphql` files from the `src` directory to the `dist` directory and follow the same folders structure.

rsync is basically a powerful transfer files utility for Unix-like operating systems. You might have it shipped with your OS system.

In my case, I needed to install it in my CI/CD pipeline (CircleCi) and added to my Dockerfile commands.

Hope it helps! Will be happy to hear about other solutions.

***EDIT***:

You can also watch for changes made in any `.graphql` files by adding the following to your `nodemonConfig` in your `package.json`:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "ext": "env,js,graphql,json",
  "watch": [
    ".env",
    "./src"
  ],
}
```